# Automatically running an installation cli script in terminal on startup

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux, startup, livecd

I created a custom Arch distro iso with [`Archiso`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso) and I wrote an installation script that prompts the user for input for install options. So far, the installation process is:

1. boot the arch iso
2. execute the installation script with:

   $ ./install.sh
3. input when prompted

Your typical-user-friendly-installer boots right to the installer and gets going. I'd like to do that by having `./install.sh` run automatically instead of being executed by the user, so that step #2 is eliminated.

if I understand correctly, the arch iso gets the user to a terminal via a systemd service that calls `/sbin/agetty`. I think I either need to modify or replace that service to make it something that calls my script, but I'm not sure how to go about that, or if this is even close to the right approach.

What's the proper way to boot to an installer script on a distro live CD?

Comment: I solved it using my own services to execute my script on a different tty and then switch the active tty to that one. I'll post an answer demonstrating this when I can work on it a little more.

Answer (score 6):

You can run a script on boot by passing the `script` kernel boot parameter in the ISOs boot loader config files.

This assumes you are using the `archiso` package to create your ISO image.

Put your script somewhere like `releng/airootfs/root/install.sh` and set the executable permission bit on the script.

In `releng/efiboot/loader/entries/archiso-x86_64-cd.conf` append `script=/root/install.sh` to the `options` line.

In `releng/syslinux/archiso_sys.cfg` append `script=/root/install.sh` to the `APPEND` line.

Comment: `script` is `archiso` boot parameter (see [README.bootparams](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/mkinitcpio/mkinitcpio-archiso/blob/master/docs/README.bootparams)). It has nothing to do with kernel.